# Internet Explorer displaying content far right

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Bit of a confusing one - on some pages of our site IE displays content on the pages really far to the right.

This is affecting a table within a body.

In the IE Boxmodel it shows the blue central box as being -184070.3. In chrome it shows the same element as being 1024.

Would setting a max-width solve this? I am confused as to why I.E is suddenly assigning the such a huge widths meaning content appears at the very right-alignment.

Comment: Adam, Show us the current code and output page/result.

Comment: Apologies, thought I had attached images but didn't seem to load.

Code: 

'<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"></table>' 

is the table element (The body content is inside this table). 

Unfortunately I haven't been able to screen-grab the issue, but as you can imagine the file would be huge as the content of this table is pushed over 184,000 pixels to the right!

Comment: please include a reproducible code snippet that we can see to debug. Cheers.

Comment: It sounds like there is a missing bit of HTML such as a </div> some browser can auto correct this type of mistake making the site display correctly. some dont

Comment: Hey all 
May have just fixed it with max-width;